# How to check whether an MLE always yields an over-estimated values?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, estimation

I have a log-likelihood function with two parameters: $\mathcal{l}(\theta_1,\theta_2)$.

When I run a simulation, the maximum likelihood estimator $\widehat{\theta}=[\widehat{\theta}_1,\widehat{\theta}_2]'$ yields a reasonable value for $\theta_1$ and an over-estimated value for $\theta_2$.

For example, if the true $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are 10 and 15, respectively, then $\widehat{\theta}_1=9.97$ and $\widehat{\theta}_2=19.5$.

In my setup, the incorrect estimate is an expected event. That is, theoretically the estimator $\widehat{\theta}_2$ is inconsistent.

However, I want to know whether the MLE **always** produces an **over**-estimated value.

Hence, my question is that **Is it possible to know whether the MLE over-estimates the parameters **always**?**

Comment: From inconsistency you cannot infer that the estimate will always be too large for any finite sample.

Comment: Along those lines, if you simulated 1000 MLEs from 1000 independent samples, all generated with known $\theta_i$ you'd have a good idea.

Comment: The situation that the MLE overestimates 'always' is not very typical. Did you possibly mean the situation that the MLE is overestimating (or biased) *on average*?

Comment: *"In  my setup, the incorrect estimate is an expected event. That is, theoretically the estimator $\hat{\theta}_2$ is inconsistent"* This is unclear. Why is your estimator inconsistent? Is it a MLE (which is supposed to be consistent) or not? What do you mean by 'is an expected event'?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Thank you for the answer. I made some subtle points in the question. As you said, what I meant is that the average of estimates from 1,000 simulation is bigger than the true value, and the `always' indicates that in many different data generating process, the average values are bigger than the true value. Also, in my setup, I know that the likelihood function is misspecified but the average value for $\widehat{\theta}_1$ seems unbiased. That is the exact situation. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ``Is it possible to know whether the MLE over-estimates the parameters always?''

Yes, for specific distributions, this is possible to know.

---

An example is the MLE for a uniform distribution $$x_i \sim U(\theta,1)$$ which has as MLE the minimum of the sample which always overestimates the true parameter

$$\hat\theta = \min(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n) > \theta $$

Another example is the MLE for the mean of a normal distribution, where we know that it is unbiased, and hence we know whether it overestimates (namely it doesn't overestimate).

---

Aside from those examples, more generally you will need to consider the distribution everytime again. I don't believe that there is an easy formula that anders you yes or no on the question whether the MLE always overestimates.

I imagine that it is possible that it is too difficult to compute/analyse the distributions, but one can always use some simulations and see whether the MLE is, for those simulations, always an overestimation of the true value.

I find it hard to come up with other situations than such cases as the uniform distribution whose domain is bounded and determined by parameters, so I guess that in practice, this method of simulations should handle most cases.

Comment: Thank you! Especially I forget that I am checking the average values of my simulation results. Your comments gave me some important points!